# PHP 7.3 not creating/writing to error log file

Tags: php, php-7, error-reporting, php-7.3

I have just upgraded to PHP 7.3 (using XAMPP) and for some reason it seems it is not writing errors to the specified log file.

I am getting deprecated errors on page output, but they don't seem to be showing up in any log file - which is more ideal since the errors aren't always visible in the page display, they get hidden in the code if they are generated between attribute values for example.

In my `php.ini` I have:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors=On
display_startup_errors=On
log_errors=On
log_errors_max_len = 2048
ignore_repeated_errors=Off
ignore_repeated_source=Off
report_memleaks=On
report_memleaks=On
html_errors=On
error_log="C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"
```

**Edit:** I just noticed today the file was created recently and it had other errors in there (ones generated from issues in php.ini itself such as deprecated settings about `track_errors`), but still not getting anything logged about issues caused by pages themselves.

**Edit 2:** I have created a separate script to generate errors on purpose and they seem t be logging fine, so I am unsure how these other ones are not logging.

Why am I not getting errors logged from pages?

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm service after adjusting the configuration?

Comment: @edigu Apache has been restarted. Also, I just noticed today it was created and it had other errors in there (ones generated from issues in `php.ini` itself such as deprecated settings), but still not getting anything logged about issues caused by pages themselves.

Comment: Restarting the HTTP server is not enough for ini changes. You should restart php-fpm service which receives the requests forwarded by apache. By the way I am a unix/mac person and don't sure if php-fpm is also restarting by xampp on HTTP server restarts.

Comment: @edigu Yes it is enough, `.ini` changes work fine after an Apache restart.

Comment: Put `<?php phpinfo();` in a file and go to the page to check you're actually using the version and INI file you think you are

Comment: @Andrea Yes it is :)

Comment: The application itself may be changing the error handling behavior.

Comment: Go to main Apache conf, and check sites enabled folder and see which dir is set in VirtualHost, varaible:ErrorLog

Comment: @MilanRilexRistic Sorry, not sure what you mean exactly by "sites enabled folder"?

Comment: @brett locate the error log file and check security permissions (right click > properties > security > advanced). See this file is writable by Apache.

Comment: @SalmanA Ok I checked that, Admins and System has full control, Users have Read & Execute and Authenticated Users have Modify.

Comment: If some scripts are logging errors and others are not that perhaps those scripts use ini_set to change error reporting settings.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
   <?php
    // Send error message to the server log if error connecting to the database
    if (!mysqli_connect("localhost","bad_user","bad_password","my_db")) {
        error_log("Failed to connect to database!", 0);
    }
    
    // Send email to administrator if we run out of FOO
    if (!($foo = allocate_new_foo())) {
        error_log("Oh no! We are out of FOOs!", 1, "admin@example.com");
    }
    ?>
```

Definition and Usage

The error_log() function sends an error message to a log, to a file, or to a mail
account.

Syntax

error_log(message,type,destination,headers);

**> Parameter   Description message Required. Specifies the error message to

> log type  Optional. Specifies where the error message should go.
>
> Possible values: 0 - Default. Message is sent to PHP's system logger,
>
> using the OS' system logging mechanism or a file, depending on what
>
> the error_log configuration is set to in php.ini 1 - Message is sent
>
> by email to the address in the destination parameter 2 - No longer in
>
> use (only available in PHP 3) 3 - Message is appended to the file
>
> specified in destination 4 - Message is sent directly to the SAPI
>
> logging handler destination   Optional. Specifies the destination of the
>
> error message. This value depends on the value of the type parameter
>
> headers   Optional. Only used if the type parameter is set to 1.
>
> Specifies additional headers, like From, Cc, and Bcc. Multiple headers
>
> should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n) Technical Details Return
>
> Value:    TRUE on success, or FALSE on failure PHP Version:   4.0+ PHP
>
> Changelog:    PHP 5.2.7: The value of 4 was added to the type parameter**